# The first quadrant is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Is the first quadrant $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x>0, y>0\}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Can anyone say if it is true and if it is how could you show it?

At first I am trying to show the homeomorphism between $(0, \infty)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. I believe that the function $ : \mathbb{R}→(0,\infty)$ where $()=^$ is the required mapping that demonstrates a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,\infty)$. (The inverse function $^{-1}$, like f, is continuous). Then the other homeomorphism, should be defined by $ : \mathbb{R}→(−\infty,0)$ where $()=−^$.

How could I now go forward to show that the first quadrant is or is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  The way this site is supposed to work is that you explain carefully what you have done and where you are stuck.  Then we help you unstuck yourself.  So, please edit your question with an explanation of your attempts so far.

Comment: Maybe try showing that the real line is homemorphic to $x>0$ first to get an idea?

Comment: And think why not  $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x\geq 0, y \geq 0\}$ .

Comment: Thank you for the quick comments! But to be honest I just started my first topology course and I know how to show that an interval is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$, but I do not understand where to even start, with a quadrant.

Comment: @sola Can you name a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,\infty)$? This should give you an idea for your problem.

Comment: If you can show that $(0,\infty)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ then there is a very straightforward way of doing same for $n$ variables. You need to experiment a little and try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $f(x) = e^x$ is a homeomorphism $\mathbb R \to (0,\infty)$; its inverse is the logarithm $\ln : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$.

The first quadrant is nothing else than $(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$. Thus
$F = f \times f : \mathbb R^2 = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to (0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$  is a homeomorphism. We have $F(x,y) = (e^x,e^y)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! But should I also show that the $e^x$ and $e^y$ are continuous functions or is this enough to prove the homeomorphism?

Comment: It is well-known that $e^x$ and $\ln y$ are continous functions which are inverse to each other. Do not give a proof of these facts,